# Isolated Azure Function missing authentication header?

Tags: azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

I have created a new .NET 6 Isolated Azure Function followed by this great article:
https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-jwt-authentication-in-net-isolated-process-azure-functions

If I'm debugging it locally, it works perfectly, the calling client attaches an authentication header to the request which I can read in the authentication middleware. But once the function app is deployed in Azure, I cannot access the authentication header in the authentication middleware, this header entry is missing. It looks like the authentication header is somehow removed from the header.

My program is

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseNewtonsoftJson();
                builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
                builder.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
                builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
                builder.Services.AddOptions<AppSettings>()
                             .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                             {
                                 configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(settings);
                             });
                builder.Services.AddPersistenceRepositories();
                builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices();
                builder.Services.AddPersistenceInfrastructures();
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpFunctionExecutor, HttpFunctionExecutor>();
            })
            .ConfigureOpenApi()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Comment: I manage to solve the issue by setting the azure function authorization level to Anonymous. So it can get the header authorization part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thank you @*jack.pop* ,For the solution ,Posting the same as answer so that other community members can beneficial for similar issue.*

***WORKAROUND:-***

> ***Please make sure to set the authorization level to [`Anonymous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#function-access-keys) as shown below*** .
>
> ```
> public static class TestFunctions
> {
>     [Authorize(
>         Scopes = new[] { "access_as_user" },
>         UserRoles = new[] { "admin" })]
>     public static HttpResponseData OnlyAdmins(
>         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
>         FunctionContext executionContext)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

For more information please refer this Blog|[***Isolated Azure Function missing authentication header and identity***](https://bytemeta.vip/repo/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/948) .